# Find td in a table from another td child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically i want to find the value of the td element of the class "number" value when i press the input button.

```
<table id="tableid">
 <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="number"> 5 </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><input type="button" onclick="value(this)"></td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
</table
```

This is the javascript which is not working:

```
function value(row) {
    var number = row.parentNode.parentNode.find("td:eq(1)").text(); 
    alert(number)
 }
```

What i'm missing?

Comment: `find()` is a jQuery method and so is `text()`.  `.parentNode` is a native Element property.  You're intermixing your logic.

Comment: Also, `row` there is a mis-labling.  From your html inline binding that variable actually is the input element.

Comment: Ok thanks now i got why is not working, but how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(row).closest('tr').find('.number').text();
```

Use closest to go up to the row, then find the element by its class, and then get its value.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I assume this is general question and you are not asking for finding dynamically created table. I suggest you to go classic JAVASCRIPT

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].innerHTML;
  alert(x);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: What if there are multiple rows?

Comment: Yet again I assume from the condition of the question that this is static table as shown in the example and only one element is with class name number in the table. Anyways here you can go with n elements of the table with the same class name  
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("number")[0].innerHTML;
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   alert(x(i));
}

Comment: Actually it is a dynamic table but i provided just the html needed for the question, thanks anyway

Comment: Jquery find is wrapper over getElementsByClassName JavaScript, there are performance penalties specially on low end handheld devices, if performance is critical issue go with native JavaScript instead. More on this https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/574/1/get-elements-by-class-jquery-vs-queryselectorall-vs-get#latest_results_block

Comment: Technically, depending on the version of jquery it could be a wrapper over `querySelectorAll`